# Reading and modifying special characters in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, unicode, ascii

I'm trying to read in a set of files using VB.Net (latest) that are using extended special characters as delimiters for data such as the upside down letter tack (Unicode: U+02D4) and the Z with a u on top "Ž" (Unicode: U+017D), replacing certain characters that shouldn't be there (such as :), and then rewriting the data back to the original file.

The problem I've ran into is that using IO.File.ReadAllLines using UTF8 doesn't recognize the Ž character especially.  I need either that character to be present in the file or the upside down letter tack to be present, as these represent delimiters in the files I'm interpreting.  Thank you in advance for any help!

Edit: Also, I'm not being paid to write this program.  I'm a data entry employee (still) and I'm trying to make life easier here at work. But I am looking to try to transition into programming.

Here's some of the code I'm using:

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RemoveDelimiters.Click
            files = IO.Directory.GetFiles(recdirectory.Text)
            If (IsNothing(files)) Then
                MsgBox("Please select a directory before attempting to parse files!")
            Else
                For Each file As String In files
                    Dim extension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file)
                    If (extension <> ".exe" And extension <> ".bat" And extension <> ".txt" And extension <> ".0") Then
                        'Dim text As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(file)
                        Dim text As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(file, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
                        Dim stext
                        stext = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(text, 300)
                        text = text.Replace(":", "")
                        text = text.Replace("`", "")
                        text = text.Replace("P*!GS*IA*FDE*", "P*:!GS*IA*FDE*")
                        'For Atkore files
                        'MsgBox(stext)
                        'text = text.Replace(ChrW(65533), ChrW(724))
                        'text = text.Replace(ChrW(65533), ChrW(381))
                        If (text.IndexOf("?") > -1) Then
                            MsgBox("found ? in file: " & file)
                        End If
                        If (text.IndexOf("P*:!GS*IA*FDE*") < 0) Then
                            If (text.IndexOf("GS*IA*FDE*") > -1) Then
                                text = text.Insert(text.IndexOf("GS*IA*FDE*") - 1, ":")
                            End If
                            If (text.IndexOf("GS*IM*FDE*") > -1) Then
                                text = text.Insert(text.IndexOf("GS*IM*FDE*") - 1, ":")
                            End If
                            If (text.IndexOf("GS*IM*FDE*") < 0 And text.IndexOf("GS*IA*FDE*") < 0) Then
                                MsgBox("Header not found for file: " & vbCrLf & file)
                            End If
                        End If
                        IO.File.WriteAllText(file, text, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
                    End If
                Next
                MsgBox("The operation has been completed!")
            End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: If Ž gets corrupted then you simply did not guess at UTF8 correctly.  This is common.  Next guess should be Encoding.Default.

Comment: Hans, if you will please post this as an answer, I will mark this as the correct answer because well...you were absolutely correct! I knew the default encoding was UTF8 when reading/writing files, but I never thought to enact the "Default" keyword.  Thanks!